# Найти периметр произвольного треугольника, если известны только основание и высота

Tags: visual-c++, алгоритм, геометрия

С равнобедренным треугольником всё понятно, высоту поделила бы пополам, и узнали бы все три стороны, но как быть в общем случае, когда треугольник может быть произвольным?

Спасибо.

Comment: Никак.....

Comment: Ну вообще печалька ...

Answer (score 2):

Можно только оценить.

Решение для равнобедренного треугольника, *ℓ* + √(*ℓ*<sup>2</sup> + 4 *h*<sup>2</sup>) — оценка снизу.

Оценка сверху — бесконечность, т. к. бывают тупоугольные треугольники (извините, хорошей картинки с высотой за пределами треугольника под рукой нет, но, думаю, вы поняли). Однако, если известно, что треугольник не тупоугольный, то максимальное значение периметра: *ℓ* + *h* + √(*ℓ*<sup>2</sup> + *h*<sup>2</sup>) (прямоугольный треугольник с катетами *ℓ* и *h*).